# Make clicking on duplicate in flag panel stay in menu

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface, flag-dialog

When you load the flag panel, select a post which is a duplicate itself, then click on the duplicate link (i.e. "this question is a exact duplicate of: ..."), it takes you out of the flag menu instead of keeping the menu showing and on the same page.  Could this behaviour be improved please?

Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about:

[image]